# header( 'Location: XXXXX );

Tags: header, location

If I have a php page that will save data from a form to the database then I want to forward that person to another place, do I have to put header( 'Location: URL ); at the end of the PHP script, or can I put it at the begining of the script and it will forward them to that page but the php script will continue to run until finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script will run either way, just be sure not to print anything before calling the `header()` function, else it's going to be ignored.